# What's the difference between "Kingdom", "Reign" and "Realm"?

Tags: meaning, difference

Can you tell some example? For me its confusing, and until now I'm using much like synonyms...

By example of some game names, that looks talking about the "same thing":

- Kingdom Hearts
- Dragon Realms
- Warcraft III: Reign of Chaos

Comment: Have you looked at what part of speech they are? What are the definitions you've read?

Comment: I would use a dictionary rather than proper names to study this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A "**kingdom**" is a country whose head of state is a king or queen, such as the UK, Denmark, Sweden, the Netherlands, Belgium, Spain, Thailand, and others.

"**Realm**" is a slightly old-fashioned or formal word for a kingdom.  It is also used metaphorically to refer an area of interest or study, such as "the realm of applied chemistry" ([Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/realm)).  The OED says of the literal meaning of "realm", "now used chiefly rhetorically and in legal contexts".  An example of the latter was in August 1914 when the British Parliament passed the Defence of the Realm Act ([DORA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defence_of_the_Realm_Act_1914)) giving the government emergency powers.

"**Reign**" is quite different.  It doesn't mean a kingdom, but it means either to rule as a monarch or to hold office as a monarch, or the period during which a particular monarch reigns ([Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/reign)) - e.g. "the reign of Queen Elizabeth II began in 1952"; "Henry VIII reigned from 1509 to 1547".  "Reign" can also be rhetorical or figurative: "chaos reigned".

Comment: So, "kingdom" is a "geopolitical" term, "realm" is like an "abstract" term, and "reign" is like a "timespan" term? I can write a sentence like this: "In the mid age, during the reign of King Arthur, the kingdom was so strong that their realm included neighboor countries"???

Comment: @ClickOk: "In the *middle ages*, during the reign of King Arthur, the kingdom was so strong that *his* realm included *neighboring* countries."

Comment: You can say that, but of course, it's not historically accurate! King Arthur is a legend, and the "real" Arthur (if he existed at all) didn't even control all of Britain.

Comment: @JamesK Thanks, James. Just testing the meaning of the 3 words in some context :)